# What information does Crome's PageEdit leak?

Tags: google-chrome

I design web sites. Checking a site in Chrome I am surprised to  find "PageEdiit" enabled in chrome://extensions/ and I am considering to use it. However, permission shows the following; 
"Access all data on website"

Because I do web development for many kinds on clients I am concerned about what data this could leak.

I have read privacy statements and visited chrome store and see http://codemirror.net/  and http://ckeditor.com are used but not sure how.

How can I find out what information is potentially leaked if I use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try another chrome extension :) (like Live HTTP Headers) but to be *sure* of what is being passed to Google use an HTTP proxy such as Fiddler, or Charles fiddler2.com to examine where packets are sent and what information they contain.